# Why am I getting a seg fault in this function?

Tags: c++

No matter what I try I keep getting a seg fault somewhere in this function.

```
int build_playlist(Song playlist[], char* inputFiles[], int numInputFiles)
{

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for( j = 0; j < numInputFiles; j++ )
    {
        FILE *file = fopen(inputFiles[j], "r");
        if (file == NULL)
            {
                printf("File could not be opened.\n");
                return -1;
            }
        while (1)
        {
            if (feof(file))
            {
                break;
            }
            fscanf(file, "%s %s %s %d", playlist[i].artist, playlist[i].title, playlist[i].album, &playlist[i].rating);

            i++;
        }
        fclose(file);
        numInputFiles++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Comment: ... use debugger, step through code, see which line it segfaults on. That should give you a strong hint.

Comment: What is `playlist`? How is it declared? How is it passed to your function? The same with `inputFiles`, what is it and how is it declared and initialized?

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing numInputFiles, because of this j will always be < numInputFiles. This causes an infinite loop, which will cause you to access memory you shouldn't access.

There are several things that can go wrong here as well:

1. You are going out of bounds on the song array. The value of i becomes to big.
2. The artist, title or album string do not have enough space to hold the strings you are trying to read in.

Answer (score 0):

You got an infinite loop that's certainly gonna access out of bounds.

```
for( j = 0; j < numInputFiles; j++ )
{
    FILE *file = fopen(inputFiles[j], "r");
```

still looks good so far. But sadly at the end of the loop you do:

```
    numInputFiles++;
}
```

`j` will never become greater than `numInputFiles` if you increment both of them in your loop. You probably want to remove the `numInputFiles++;` line.

Also we can't see the declaration of the `playlist` array but since you nowhere check for the size of `playlist` you might also run the risk of accessing out of bounds.